# KeyError when printing dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, input, keyerror

So I am trying to write a program where the user enters the course number and then gets the room, instructor, and meeting times information for that course. I want to be able to print a termination message if the user inputs a course that is not found/valid, but when I try, it comes up with a KeyError.
I have tried using a try/except statement, but when I execute the code it comes up with a TypeError.

```
room_dict = {
    "CS101": {
        "Room": "3004"
    },
    "CS102": {
        "Room": "4501"
    },
    "CS103": {
        "Room": "6755"
    },
    "NT110": {
        "Room": "1244"
    },
    "CM241": {
        "Room": "1411"
    },
}


instructor_dict = {
    "CS101": {
        "Instructor": "Haynes"
    },
    "CS102": {
        "Instructor": "Alvarado"
    },
    "CS103": {
        "Instructor": "Rich"
    },
    "NT110": {
        "Instructor": "Burkes"
    },
    "CM241": {
        "Instructor": "Lee"
    },
}


time_dict = {
    "CS101": {
        "Time": "8:00 a.m."
    },
    "CS102": {
        "Time": "9:00 a.m."
    },
    "CS103": {
        "Time": "10:00 a.m."
    },
    "NT110": {
        "Time": "11:00 a.m."
    },
    "CM241": {
        "Time": "1:00 p.m."
    },
}

courses = {"CS101", "CS102", "CS103", "NT110", "CM241"}
dicts = {'Room':room_dict,'Instructor':instructor_dict,'Time': time_dict}

dash_count = 50
dashes = dash_count * "-"

print(f'College Course Locater Program')
print(f'Enter a course number below to get information')
get_course = input(f'Enter a course number: ')
print(dashes)

course_num = get_course
room = room_dict[get_course]
instructor = instructor_dict[get_course]
time = time_dict[get_course]

if course_num in courses:
    print(f'The details for course {get_course} are: ')
    print(f"Room: {room['Room']}")
    print(f"Time: {time['Time']}")
    print(f"Instructor: {instructor['Instructor']}")
```

else:
print(course_num, 'is an invalid course number.')

Basically, the output I am getting is:

```
College Course Locater Program
Enter a course number below to get information
Enter a course number: CS # where CS is an invalid course number
--------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Python\Downloads\courseinfo.py", line 75, in <module>
    room = room_dict[get_course]
KeyError: 'CS'
```

What I am looking for is:

```
College Course Locater Program
Enter a course number below to get information
Enter a course number: CS
--------------------------------------------------
(course number) is an invalid course number. # where (course number) is an invalid course number
```

Answer (score 3):

Multiple problems:

First, you check `if get_course == room_dict:`. But `room_dict` is *the entire dictionary!* It can never be equal to the course number you entered.

Second, there's no need to loop `for item in room_dict.items():`. Values in a dictionary are supposed to be accessed using their *keys*. So you'd do something like

```
get_course = input(f'Enter a course number: ')

print(f'The details for course {get_course} are: ')
room = room_dict[get_course]
instructor = instructor_dict[get_course]
time = time_dict[get_course]
print(f"Room: {room['Room']}, Time: {time['Time']}, Instructor: {instructor['Instructor']}")
```

Of course, you'd need to make sure `get_course` exists as a key in all those dictionaries. You can do that by

- [Look before you leap](https://docs.python.org/3.5/glossary.html#term-lbyl) by checking that the key exists explicitly: `if get_course in room_dict:` or,
- Using a try-except to catch a KeyError. After all, it's [easier to ask for forgiveness than permission](https://docs.python.org/3.5/glossary.html#term-eafp)

```
try:
    room = room_dict[get_course]
    instructor = instructor_dict[get_course]
    time = time_dict[get_course]
except KeyError:
    print("Course info not found")
```

Even better, you could redefine your dicts so that one single dict contains all the information about the courses.

```
course_info = {
    "CS101": {
        "Room": "3004",
        "Instructor": "Haynes",
        "Time": "8:00 a.m."
    },
    "CS102": {
        "Room": "4501",
       "Instructor": "Alvarado",
       "Time": "9:00 a.m."
    }
# and so on
}
```

And then simply do:

```
get_course = input(f'Enter a course number: ')

try:
    crs = course_info[get_course]
    print(f'The details for course {get_course} are: ')
    print(f"Room: {crs['Room']}, Time: {crs['Time']}, Instructor: {crs['Instructor']}")
except KeyError:
    print(f"Details not found for {get_course}")
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below should make your life easier.

It uses `course_name = 'CM241'` for demo purpose only.

```
room_dict = {
    "CS101": {
        "Room": "3004"
    },
    "CS102": {
        "Room": "4501"
    },
    "CS103": {
        "Room": "6755"
    },
    "NT110": {
        "Room": "1244"
    },
    "CM241": {
        "Room": "1411"
    },
}


instructor_dict = {
    "CS101": {
        "Instructor": "Haynes"
    },
    "CS102": {
        "Instructor": "Alvarado"
    },
    "CS103": {
        "Instructor": "Rich"
    },
    "NT110": {
        "Instructor": "Burkes"
    },
    "CM241": {
        "Instructor": "Lee"
    },
}


time_dict = {
    "CS101": {
        "Time": "8:00 a.m."
    },
    "CS102": {
        "Time": "9:00 a.m."
    },
    "CS103": {
        "Time": "10:00 a.m."
    },
    "NT110": {
        "Time": "11:00 a.m."
    },
    "CM241": {
        "Time": "1:00 p.m."
    },
}

dicts = {'Time':time_dict,'Room':room_dict,'Instructor': instructor_dict}
course_name = 'CM241'
for k,v in dicts.items():
  print(f'{k} --> {v[course_name][k]}')
```

output

```
Time --> 1:00 p.m.
Room --> 1411
Instructor --> Lee
```

Comment: This works really well, but now I am having a hard time getting it to display the "course details" message without it printing several times. I think I need another way of formatting the results of the code.

Comment: Glad to help. I am sure you will solve the print issue. Feel free to up vote.

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_